# Angular - Is it possible to Develope app located on a webserver

Tags: angular, deployment, web-deployment

Im struggling to find a solution with google. Is it possible to deploy an angular application on a Webserver and to develop on it? If so how can i start the App? Do i need to Run "ng serve" with the public ip of the Server? E.g. "ng serve --host 127.90.120....". If this may be not possible, do i need some Kind of Development Server (dev-server)? And how would i approach this? Im asking cause i want to fetch data from an API. And i can only fetch the Data with a token as Parameter of the http request. And this token is only valid on a Public IP.

Answer (score 1):

Angular as any other Javascript framework will work in any static content server. You don't use `ng serve` in the server. You build your code `npm run build` and then you deploy that to any server you like that can serve static content (you can do it in github or firebase if you want). If want you are looking for is having SSR capabilities you might want to take a look to this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geckI2J6naM&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkbvTj8AUUCfBO7DoEHJ-ME